# Python script that allows me to load multiple cells from a spreadsheet that are in the clipboard and paste each individual cell one at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyperclip

I'm trying to copy multiple cells from a table of a document and I want to be able to press a hotkey that will act as a paste function, pasting one cell at a time starting with the first.

| data |
| --- |
| Cell 1 |
| Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |

**Hotkey** *paste* Cell 1, **Hotkey** *paste* Cell 2, **Hotkey** *paste* Cell 3

```
import pandas as pd
import keyboard
import pyperclip

df = []
var = 0

def load_cells():
    print("Load Hotkey pressed")
    global df, var
    df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", names=["vals"])
    var = len(df)
    return df
    
def paste_cell():
    print("paste Hotkey pressed")
    global df, var
    if var < len(df):
        pyperclip.copy(str(df.iloc[var, 0]))
        var += 1

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+x', load_cells)
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+z', paste_cell)   
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+a', print(df))
```

My current error is "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" but I've be struggling with many versions of this and think I think I'm not headed in the right direction.

Print functions added to attempt to locate errors but I haven't been able to get anything loaded to the dataframe.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet because I don't have fifty rep. But are you saying that when you press a hotkey you get a TypeError? If so that means the function you are trying to call is `not defined`, what about when you press the hotkey that calls `print(df)`? I'll edit my answer once I get some more information.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When I have content copied in my clipboard and I use the ctrl+alt+x hotkey, I don't think anything is being added to the dataframe.

I get "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" when using either other hotkey afterwards